# Nexus 7 refuses to boot unless plugged into outlet

Tags: battery, nexus-7, boot, power-on

I've looked around the internet for this problem ad/or solution for hours and have found absolutely nothing on this problem.
My tablet is brand new, straight from the box.

When i have it plugged in and turn it on, theres absolutely NO problems at all. Everything works like it should and the battery is detected and charges fine (at 100%). I can even unplug it after booting it and it will continue to run.

Now if i try to turn it on without it being plugged in first, it refuses to turn on. 
I tried the 30+ second power hold with no result.
I also took the back off and disconnected/reconnected the battery port but it still doesnt work.
Anyone have any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

We'll there is no fix for this. I have had my N7 for one month and it is doing the same thing described--if it is not plugged in it will not start up. So here is what I have experienced relative to this problem.  First the N7 I just pulled out of the box did the same thing. So I brought it back to the store to exchange it and to be safe I tried the next three at the store and they all had the same problem.  The fourth one worked for a month. Now that it will not start up I called Google they would help only if I bought it through the PlayStore.  They passed me to Asus who gave me only one option -  return to have it repaired not replaced.  I am very disappointed in Google.  They know they have a problem but do not want to say so in the public. Very sad